# How to filter a select-string to only display the found word with wildcard

Tags: powershell

I am using

```
Select-String -Path "some\path\smthing.xml" -pattern "smthing*"
```

which displays the whole line that contains this pattern.
The problem is that there are random numbers after smthing and are always different so I can only use wildcard.

How to filter that result to display only the matching string, ie - smthing44326 instead of the whole line of the file?

Comment: If the file is actually an XML, treating it as such might be a cleaner way to do it than using regex.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon doesnt matter, even if its a txt, it displays the entire line and I need only the word found.

Comment: You're probably looking for `Select-String -Pattern 'smething\d+' | % { $_.Matches.Value }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon mate, post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Regex and wildcards are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use a pattern to match specifically `smthing` followed by **one or more numbers (`\d+`)**, then once you have the right pattern you need to reference the [`.Matches.Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-capture-value) from the [objects outputted by `Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.matches?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#microsoft-powershell-commands-matchinfo-matches):

```bash
Select-String -Path some\path\smthing.xml -Pattern 'smthing\d+' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a string context, it will just be a string.  Also piping in the file contents.  Without the double-quotes, it will have other properties.

```
$a = get-content file | select-string hi
"$a"

hi
```

Only the regex match.  `.*` wouldn't work, unless it was the last thing on the line.  Powershell 7 also highlights matches.

```
set-content file hi123` there
$a = get-content file | select-string hi\S*
$a | % matches | % value

hi123
```

Comment: coercing to string a MatchInfo instance resolves to the `Line` property not to `.Matches.Value`. Not what OP wants.